# how to remove .ts (mp3) header and other information at the start of audio file

Tags: c#

I try to play audio file that transfering via .ts (mp3) parts and i must play it as soon as first ts downloaded (like buffering), but since they are parts, all of them have header and other info at the start of file and when i try to play it sequently i heard stuttering when other part starting play because of header (i think)[image]

I tried to use ffmpeg to convert .ts to .wav and NAduio to play

```
bool result = await FFMpegArguments
    .FromPipeInput(new StreamPipeSource(new MemoryStream(data)))
    .OutputToPipe(new StreamPipeSink(output), options => options
        .ForceFormat("wav")
        .SelectStream(0, 0)
        .WithCustomArgument("-fflags +bitexact -flags:v +bitexact -flags:a +bitexact"))
    .ProcessAsynchronously();

if (bufferedWaveProvider == null)
{
    bufferedWaveProvider = new BufferedWaveProvider(new WaveFormat(44100, 16, 2));
    bufferedWaveProvider.BufferDuration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
}

bufferedWaveProvider.AddSamples(output.ToArray(), 0, (int)output.Length);

if (waveOut == null)
{
    waveOut = new WaveOut();

    waveOut.Volume = 0.4f;
    waveOut.Init(bufferedWaveProvider);
    waveOut.Play();
}
```

also adding -c copy to ffmpeg plays white noise.

And also tried WindowsMediaPlayer via playlist

```
WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer player = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();

WMPLib.IWMPPlaylist playlist = player.playlistCollection.newPlaylist("NewPlaylist");
player.currentPlaylist = playlist;

bool result = await FFMpegArguments
        .FromPipeInput(new StreamPipeSource(new MemoryStream(data)))
        .OutputToPipe(new StreamPipeSink(output), options => options
            .ForceFormat("wav")
            .SelectStream(0, 0)
            .WithCustomArgument("-c copy -fflags +bitexact -flags:v +bitexact -flags:a +bitexact"))
        .ProcessAsynchronously();

File.WriteAllBytes($"{i}.wav", output.ToArray());

WMPLib.IWMPMedia fileMedia = player.newMedia($"{i}.wav");
playlist.appendItem(fileMedia);

if (i == 0)
    player.controls.play();
```